# Change Union type to Union of arrays of type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to create a helper generic type to make changes to all types within a union?

For example these 4 types that could be some proper interfaces with lots of properties

```
type A = 'a'

type B = 'b'

type C = 'c'

type D = 'd'

type unionForArr = A | B | C | D

type desired<unionForArr> = A[] | B[] | C[] | D[]

type wrong = unionForArr[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type ToArrays<T> = T extends T ? T[] : never;

type UnionForArr = 'a' | 'b' | 'c' | 'd'
type Desired = ToArrays<UnionForArr> // 'a'[] | 'b'[] | 'c'[] | 'd'[]
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=3&ssc=6&pln=3&pc=17#code/C4TwDgpgBAKg9gQQE5IIYgM4B4YD4oC8sUEAHsBAHYAmGxA-LANoC6UAXFJRAG4RIBuALAAoUaEhQAqpQCWcSgDE4SZEkJQA5Kk1QAPloBGug5oDGJrdU3jw0ACIQMspBGob4a9NhnylKtVwgA)

Comment: as it's written there it seems that you'd need to repeat the entire type definitions in the `UnionForArr` definition?

Comment: This is perfect thank you, I just needed the generic to change all types given into arrays based on the given types